# Name for (input, output) tuples of a function

Tags: functions

What is the name for a tuple of the form $(x, y)$ with respect to some $f: X → Y$ where $x ∊ X$, $y ∊ Y$ and $y = f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -

The ordered pair $\ (x\ f(x))\ $ is a point of the graph of the function $\ f$.

> -
>
> -

Indeed -- *thank you @EthanBolker for prompting me to expand on the above*

-- the graph $\ \Gamma_f\ $ of function $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is the following set:

$$ \Gamma_f\ :=\ \{ (x\ f(x))\ :\ x\in X\} $$

It's even customary to define a function $\ f\ $ as an ordered
triple $\ (X\ Y\ \Gamma)\ $ where set $\ X\ $ is called the domain
of $\ f,\ $ set $\ Y\ $ is called the range of function $\ f\ $, and
the set $\ \Gamma\subseteq X\times Y\ $ has two properties:

- $\ \forall_{x\in X}\,\exists_{y\in Y}\quad (x\ y)\ \in\ \Gamma;$
- $\ \forall_{x\in X}\,\forall_{y\,z\in Y}\ ((x\ y)\,\ (x\ z)\in \Gamma)
  \ \Rightarrow\ y=z) $

Then $\ \Gamma_f\ := \Gamma,\ $ and for each
$\ (x\ y)\in\Gamma\ $ we write $\ y=f(x).$

Comment: +1 This might be the answer the OP is looking for. You might edit to point out that given the customary definition of a function as a set of ordered pairs, these pairs are elements of the function. A function _is_ its graph.